# Reverse engineering LCD module pinout and finding a replacement

Tags: lcd

I trying to reverse engineer an LCD module with no useful markings (datasheets etc). It is for sure a 128 X 64 LCD matrix of some sort, as I counted the dots in a closeup picture of a working one.

There are 12 pins on the cable going into the LCD display module. The backlight is a separate thing.

The LCD display module is fed by a ROLAND R8A02021ABG, but I do not have the schematic for this particular unit. What I do have is a schematic for another Roland unit (integra 7) that uses the same R8A02021ABG. In this schematic I can see that there looks to be 18 pins that feed the LCD display of that unit.

What I am after is how this 18 pins listed below may also work for a 12 pin LCD.

These are the names of the LCD associated PINS as far as I can tell.

**NOT PIN NUMBERS, ONLY FOR THIS REFERNCE**

1. GDB_RXD
2. GDB_TXD
3. SSC_IO1
4. SSC_IO0
5. SSC_RXD
6. SSC_TXD
7. UOVCD
8. UVBON
9. SSC_IO2
10. LCD-CS
11. LCD-CD
12. LCD-SO
13. LCD-CLK

**MAY or MAY NOT Be associated with LCD function**

14. XRST
15. DGND
16. CP1.2V
17. DGND
18. DGND

I'm trying to understand these pin functions by name and see how these "names" may also be able to feed a "12 pin" version of a 128 X 64 LCD display.

Comment: Repair questions are off topic here when not supported by detailed design documentation.  Either ask on a Roland user forum, or start reverse engineering - eg, check the voltage levels with a scope, then dive in with a logic analyzer and see what seems to be going on.

Comment: I edited the question. You're right,  this really isn't a repair issue. I'm trying to see what the naming convention I posted means and how it may fit in with a "12 pin" version of an LCD module that can be driven from the same IC, e.g. the roland R8A02021ABG

Comment: We don't really take "do you recognize this scheme?" questions, rather EESE is about questions supported by required information.  So basically, you need to probe this yourself and see what is going on.

Comment: I'd look and see if I can find the schematic for the entire synth or whatever instrument this is for first.

Comment: Schematic is not available. Chris, your point is taken. I'm new to LCD functions, but not new to the other stuff. At this point I'm just curious as to the naming convention.